# How to read two rows values at the same time from a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

How can I read values from two consecutive rows from `SqlDataReader` at the same time ?!

```
SqlCommand query2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT lon , lat FROM Student Where B_ID = @B_ID ORDER BY Distance ASC");
// some value for @B_ID
            query2.Connection = cn;
SqlDataReader readStd = query2.ExecuteReader();
while (readStd.Read())
            {
                // here I want to calculate the distance between each consecutive rows 
// by taking the latitude and longitude from each row
                    double d = DistanceBetweenPlaces(Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(0)), Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(1)), ???, ???);
                    totalDistance = totalDistance + d;
                //}
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a temp variable ?

Comment: Why not just read the two rows in succession, storing the values in local variables, and then perform the calculation on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly. Each call to `SqlDataReader.Read` advances the reader, allowing you to retrieve the values of the row it is pointing too. Therefore you can't "read two rows at the same time". Refer to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you can do, however, is using some temporary values like that :

```
SqlCommand query2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT lon , lat FROM Student Where B_ID = @B_ID ORDER BY Distance ASC");
    // some value for @B_ID
    query2.Connection = cn;
    SqlDataReader readStd = query2.ExecuteReader();
    double tempLong = 0.0;
    double tempLat = 0.0;
    bool isFirstIteration = true;
    while (readStd.Read())
        {
            if(isFirstIteration)
            {
                isFirstIteration = false;
            }
            else
            {
                double d = DistanceBetweenPlaces(tempLong, tempLat, Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(0)), Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(1)));
                totalDistance = totalDistance + d;
            }
            tempLong = Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(0));
            tempLat = Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(1));            
        }
```

Not tested (and maybe wrong because I don't know your method definition), but I think you will get the general idea.